# Tornado set_secure_cookie

Tags: python, cookies, tornado

When I set a value in a `set_secure_cookie` function in Python Tornado, I can get the value whit a `get_secure_cookie` function when I make a `redirec`, but when I use a render action it doesn't appear.

```
form = UserAddForm(self.request.arguments)
if form.validate():
    record = User(**form.data)
    self.db.add(record)
    self.db.commit()
    self.set_secure_cookie("flash", "success")
    self.redirect("/user") # Show the flash message with self.get_secure_cookie("flash")
else:
    self.set_secure_cookie("flash", "error")
    self.render("user/add.html", form=form) # Don't show the flash message with self.get_secure_cookie("flash")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function "set_cookie" will set cookie in the HTTP response header which will effect in the next request.